# some documentation/book about creating kernel modules for linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

some documentation/book about creating kernel modules for linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux Documentation Project: Guides

http://tldp.org/guides.html

[PDF] Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide

techpubs.sgi.com/library/manuals/0000/860.../860-0239-001.pdf